# How to print out how many times does QuickSort does switches and checks?

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I have this task where I have to do a research about quicksort algorithm and I have to measure how many time does this algorithm checks numbers (if statements) and switches them. Afterwards I need to print out 2 variables that show how many times were number checked and switched. I think I'm having issues because I'm using a recursive function but I cannot think of a better way to write the code.

```cpp
void quickSort(int* arr, int low, int high, int checks, int switches){

    switches++;
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    int temp;
    int pivot = arr[(i + j) / 2];
    checks++;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        checks++;


        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;

        checks++;


        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        checks++;


        if (i <= j)
        {

            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    checks++;

    if (j > low) {
        quickSort(arr, low, j, checks, switches);
    }
    checks++;

    if (i < high) {
        quickSort(arr, i, high, checks, switches);
    }
        cout << checks<<" "<<switches << endl;
}
```

I'm printing out checks and switches variables after both if's but numbers get printed several times (if array is big for example arr[400] these numbers get printed insanely huge amount of times). I tried to make quicksort function an INT function and return those variables to main and then print them out but my attempt was unsuccessful. I also tried to write another if statement `if(j< low && i>high) {cout << checks<<" "<<switches << endl;}`, but it just wouldn't print.

Any help or useful information on how I could improve my code is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably start by writing functions for switching (aka swapping) and checking (aka comparing).  Increment your counters in the functions.

Comment: As I can see, your if(j  < low && i > high) won't work because while you decrease and increase their value they will become equal to low or high. So if (j <= low && i >= high) would work and your print would work.

Comment: Take `checks` and `switches` by reference (`int&`) and then print them after the top-level call to `quickSort()` in your user code.

Comment: @SlothCoding unfortunately I'm getting the same issue

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Tried it aswell but it didn't work. Unless I did some mistakes. Could you please show me how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make `checks` and `switches` global variables.
2. 

```
while (arr[i] < pivot)
    i++;
    checks++;
```

Shouldn't this be

```
while (arr[i] < pivot) {
    i++;
    checks++;
} 
checks++;
```

Thank you @NateEldridge for pointing out the last check which terminated the loop must also be counted, hence the `checks++` at the end.

3.

```
if (i <= j)
        {

            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
```

In this code you are swapping `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` and so you should update `switches`.

4. In some places you are updating `checks` and `switches` for seemingly no reason; it seems you should only update `checks` in `arr[i] < pivot` and `arr[j] > pivot`.

Comment: Close, but `while (arr[i] < pivot) { i++; checks++; }` doesn't count the last check which terminated the loop.